# Why EXPLAIN MYSQL query giving different results?

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

I am using same mysql query with different values and explain gives different results for them.
[image: Please Ref to image]

This is my index status
[image: Index Status]

Comment: I have added show index in update post please have look

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: This is caused because the `type='news'` is probably occurring less often than `type='article'`. When looking for articles it is smarter to do a read on PRIMARY, en when looking for news it's smarter to use the index on type.

Comment: Check output of: `SELECT type, count(*) FROM cm_article WHERE type in ('article','news') GROUP BY type ;` to confirm this.

Comment: @Luuk the query using `type='news'` is using the primary key index to do a top N style query plan, this would actually suggest it expects to find rows that match this condition more often.

Comment: @AndrewSayer: you are right, I must have accidently switched the two options...